# character space of a non unital abelian c*-algebra is locally compact

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I would like to know why character space of a unital abelian c*-algebra is compact, while the charecter space of a non unital is locally compact.
Why do we add 0 to character space of a non unital one? Why do not we add another point of unit ball A* to character space to make it compact?

Comment: Because the noncompacity is precisely that 0 is not in the set! You cannot turn $[0,1)$ into a compact subspace of $\mathbb R$ by adding the point $2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the Banach-alaoglu theorem, the character space is a subset of a compact space (the closed unit ball of the dual space). Now suppose that $A$ is not unital, and let $B$ be the standard unitisation of $A$. Then the map which sends the unit in $B$ to 1 and is identically zero on $A$ is a character. This corresponds to the zero character on $A$. The addition of this character gives the one point compactificaton of the character space of $A$.